# Geonodes repeat animation

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, animation-nodes

So here's my situation. I was tasked with making arrows flying around this machine. Instead of doing it in my old method I wanted to try and do it with Geonodes.

so I made an arrow head and animated it running throughout the machine. The geonodes helped me create the effect of the arrows splitting apart and coming back together at the end but the issue is I can't really duplicate and offset the animation easily like I thought I could. There needs to be over a hundred arrows running throughout the machine.

I thought that there were animation nodes or something that had a repeat with offset that would essentially allow me to create as many duplicated arrows as I needed.

right now my process to add more arrows is to

1. duplicate the mesh
2. turn the mesh into it's own mesh[image]
3. turn the geonode into it's own goenode for that mesh [image]
4. manually grab the keyframes and scoot them down the timeline until the arrows are spaced properly [image]
5. repeat

now I am going to probably do it manually this time but I wanted to make this post to see if anyone knows of a way to duplicate and offset an animation with geonodes... easier...

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to utilize nodes related to curves. I gave it a rough try, and my approach was to sample the coefficients of the curve and then pass the positions to the instances.I'm not sure if this effect is what you're looking for.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes curves would work for this but I guess what I am looking for is a faster way to duplicate a pre-made animation with an offset. Just like a repeat node that just keeps the animation running and I can make an offset of that with the nodes so that every duplicate I make it's automatically further down the path I animated.